# Upgrading Matlab and ensuring that the "Documents" folder's contents remain intact?

Tags: installation, updates, uninstall, matlab

I have a Matlab installation on Windows Vista given to me by the University I am in. The problem is that it does not contain many toolboxes that I need. I plan to purchase it myself with all the tool boxes. When I installed Matlab, it created a directory in the "Documents" folder for all of my files that I created. Will a new installation of Matlab let me replace the older one and add the toolboxes without touching the Documents folder?

I have a SpiderOak synchronization to that folder in "Documents" so I am unsure that if I hold a back up copy somewhere and just paste it back in that this won't create some problems.

What is the best course of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uninstall` feature of matlab does not affect the user data in the `Documents` folder. The uninstallation process leaves useful files like the command history for future installations' use. Reinstallation did not create any problems and toolboxes were added normally.